# Listen to an event temporarily i.e. "unlisten"?

Tags: laravel-5.3

Is it possible in Laravel to remove a **specific** event listener that I added, rather than **ALL** listeners listening to a given event (which is what `forget($event)` does)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple method to do so - after inspecting the Illuminate (v4.2) code when needing the same feature, I can see the forget is the only way and removes all listeners, for all priorities for an event.

However you could get all the listeners with `getListeners($eventName)`, process the returned array removing your specific listener, forget the event, then re-listen to the remaining listeners. Pretty horrible and would bind your code to the inner structure of the Event implementation.

Otherwise you could flag inside your listener to "ignore" messages from now on.

Another idea is to add a listener before your listener, and return false in its event handler, which stops even propagation! Of course this stops all subsequent subscribers from receiving the event. If you know the subscription sequence it might help, but is messy.

It seems like an obvious missing feature, but possibly because of the typical use of PHP for short-lived processes. I'm writing a worker which lasts for days, so I also need to add/remove listeners dynamically. Laravel's penchant for statics makes this difficult.

I'm considering using a "resubscribe all" routine which just forgets all events and resubscribes everything from scratch with the current config.